# Чтение файла C#

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Пытаюсь сделать чтение файла. Но выскакивает `Exception` на строчке:

`FileText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(fileRead);`

```
public string FileText { get; set; }

public async void OpenFile()
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker()
    {
        ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List,
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder,
    };
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

    IStorageFile fileRead = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (fileRead != null)
    {
        model.FileName = fileRead.Name;
        FileText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(fileRead);
        OnPropertyChanged("FileText");
    }
}
```

Comment: FileText - это переменная типа string

Comment: какое сообщение получаете в исключении?

Comment: Исключение не показывает, кидает в файл App.g.i.cs и выводит ошибку на следующей строчке:

Comment: if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: Ну так поместите это всё в блок try/catch, и поставьте breakpoint внутри catch.

Comment: @NikitaGoncharyk Ну и что "исключение не показывает"? Без этого на ваш вопрос смогут ответить только телепаты. Так что воспользуйтесь советом ВладД и учитесь пользоваться отладчиком.

Comment: Возможно у вас выбрана версия Release? И исходные файлы отличаются

Comment: необработанное исключение win32 произошло в проекте ... [10568]

Comment: Все давно уже проверил через отладчик, Путь к файлу верный и так далее, но почему выскакивает Exception я так и не понял.

Comment: Код чтения файла с этого сайта тоже не запускается
https://metanit.com/sharp/uwp/12.4.php

Comment: Мммм... Я тестировал программу на большом текстовом файле, со всеми возможными символами и на этом файле программа слетала, а когда создал новый файл и поместил туда пару строчек инфы, то все прошло нормально.